# Visual Studio 2015- Project files not displayed in Solution Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, restore, solution-explorer

Having got to a point where my code no longer works, I decided to restore a backup I had made using Git. I followed the tutorial at: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-checkout for checking out the working backup that I had made, but for some reason, the 'Solution Explorer' in Visual Studio 2015 is not showing the file structure for my project... so although I can view the three files that I already had open before restoring the backup (they have been reloaded, so they now display the state they were in at the time of the backup), I can't see any of the other source files of my project, or any of its structure...

Anyone have any idea why this is? What do I need to do to display the 'tree' structure of my project, with all of the source files, etc?

Visual studio is currently just displaying the 'project name' in the solution explorer, and none of its children- but I can't 'expand' it to see the source files, etc.

[image: Screenshot of visual studio]

In case it makes a difference- I did make a new Git branch, and checked out my backup to that new branch, rather than the one I was working in... but I wouldn't have thought that that would cause any issues?

Comment: Top result for googling "gitclone project solution explorer empty" yet no answers after nearly 2 years?!